# birt-designer: dynamic image size based on xml property

Tags: javascript, birt

I am trying to dynamically set the height of an image in the BIRT report designer, I hoped this would be possible in the General tab of an element. But there I can only set a fixed size in px, in, %, etc... 
And if I define the size as 50% for example, then it is 50% of the original image size and not 50% of my page width

I have the following javascript which van set the size of an image to a fixed size when some XML property is either `SMALL`, `MEDIUM` or `LARGE`, but when the size is SMALL, I want the image width 1/3 of the page width, and MEDIUM should be 2/3 and LARGE 3/3. So is it possible to get the page size from some variable/object from the script tab in Birt-report designer

```
if(row["size"] == "SMALL") {
    this.width = "150PX";
}
else if(row["size"] == "MEDIUM") {
    this.width = "250PX";
}
else if(row["size"] == "LARGE") {
    this.width = "350PX";
}
```

Comment: If you know how large your page is going to be, why not just set the image width to the page width * 1/3 (or 2/3, or 1, as appropriate)?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do, but how do I get the page width?

Comment: Don't you know how large your page is? Or do you intend to reuse the code in pages of varying sizes?

Comment: I just want to to be as correct and flexible as possible so therefore I would like to avoid hard coded widths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the width of your page, use the following script:

```
var width = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getMasterPages().get(0).getProperty("width");
```

Assuming you only have a single Master Page in your report.